# Slick slider change speed after change

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

What i want achieve is to change autoplay speed when the first animation will be loaded.

I found that slick has afterChange function but I don't know how to use it.

My code:

```
  $(".home-slider-t").slick({
      dots: false,
      arrows: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 2500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      fade: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 6000
  });
```

I want to set autoplay speed to 15 000ms after first change. (infinite true)

Answer (score 3):

Please note: If you provide a demo of your problem in jsfiddle help us to help you better because this is a plugin. anyways lets see what options we have:

First initialize the plugin

```
$(".home-slider-t").slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 2500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  autoplay: true,
  fade: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 6000,
});
```

and then use slick plugin events and methods:

```
$(".home-slider-t").on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $(".home-slider-t").slick('slickSetOption', 'autoplaySpeed', '15000');
});
```

p.s: Hope this code help to get idea of using methods and events of this plugin.
i couldn't check the code because you didn't provide any jsfiddle but seems its fine.

Comment: @DawidKwiatoń You are very wellcome if this helped you please set it as an answer